# Error when trying to set variable on LISP in a BMI problem

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

It's a simple college problem. I have to get the result using the BMI calc

My code below:

```
(write-line "BMI CALC")
(defun calc nil
  (prog (w h) ; define p e h as local variables init with nil
      (print "Weight: ")
      (setq w (read))
      (print "Height: ")
      (setq h (read))
      (return (/ w (* h h)))
  )
)

(format t "BMI: ~D~%" (calc))


(setq bmi calc)

(cond 
  ((< bmi 18.5) (print "Under weight"))
  ((< bmi 24.9) (print "Normal weight"))
  ((< bmi 29.9) (print "Overweight"))
  ((< bmi 34.9) (print "Obesity 1"))
  ((< bmi 39.9) (print "Obesity 2"))
  (t (print "Obesity 3"))
)
```

And I got this result below:

```
BMI CALC
"Weight: " 78
"Height: " 1.7
BMI: 26.989618
*** - SETQ:variable CALC has no value
```

I really don't understand why this error.

I expected to print the BMI result, like "Under weight" or "Obesity 1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What value do you think variable `calc` has on this line: `(setq bmi calc)`?

Because, as that error says, it doesn't have any.

Also, ending parentheses belong to the same line and you should read about [`let`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/s_let_l.htm) (a special operator for creating local variables).

Here is an improved version, which you can test by calling `(my-bmi)`:

```
(defun calc ()
  (prog (w h)
    (print "Weight: ")
    (setq w (read *query-io*))
    (print "Height: ")
    (setq h (read *query-io*))
    (return (/ w (* h h)))))

(defun my-bmi ()
  (print "BMI CALC")
  (let ((bmi (calc)))
    (format t "BMI: ~D~%" bmi)
    (print 
     (cond 
      ((< bmi 18.5) "Under weight")
      ((< bmi 24.9) "Normal weight")
      ((< bmi 29.9) "Overweight")
      ((< bmi 34.9) "Obesity 1")
      ((< bmi 39.9) "Obesity 2")
      (t "Obesity 3")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Remarks about your code

- You are using a global variable and writing the whole assignment as a script: namely you call `(setq bmi ...)` where `bmi` is not introduced by a `let`. And there is very few reusable parts. It's a bit of a bad practice to have side-effects like that. Here you are only writing a small program for an assignment so it is not very bad but, as you are also learning programming, you should also try to structure your code as small functions that don't have side-effects. This would be cleaner and would help the program grow in a real situation.
- This is related to the previous point, but you are mixing different things in functions: parsing input, computing the BMI, outputting the result. In practice we often need to architecture code into layers: here you can have a pure mathematics data layer that computes the BMI, a input/ouptut layer that prompt for values, and a main program that glues all of those parts together.
- Regarding I/O, you are likely to experience difficulties later if you don't flush the output or clear the input streams during your interactions with the user: as streams are typically buffered, sometimes `format` won't display immediately a string and this will be confusing. Using `force-output` is a way to flush all the buffers and ensure the user sees the text you wrote.

#### Alternative implementation

This is an example of how I would do it, using intermediate functions to encapsulate different tasks.

For example:

```
(defun bmi-formula (&key height weight)
  (/ weight (* height height)))
```

This is a function that you can invoke interactively as follows in the REPL:

```
CL-USER> (bmi-formula :height 1.80 :weight 60)
18.51852
```

Notice that it only computes a value from numerical values, there is no parsing involved.

Likewise, you can convert a BMI to an obesity judgment as follows (as an aside, using BMI for that is an outdated practice, I am a bit suprised/annoyed that you are being asked to write this function):

```
(defun bmi-obesity-judgment (bmi)
  (cond
    ((< bmi 18.5) 'underweight)
    ;; etc.
    ))
```

Here the function takes a `bmi` and returns a symbol. If you want later to localize your application in another language, you can map each symbol to a word in another language (e.g. `(ecase judgment (underweight "magro") ...)` please forgive my attempt at Portuguese).

Now you can write a function that grabs input from the user. Typically I would write an auxiliary function as follows:

```
(defun prompt (message type)
  (loop
    (clear-input *query-io*)
    (fresh-line *query-io*)
    (write-string message *query-io*)
    (let ((value (read *query-io*)))
      (when (typep value type)
        (return value))
      (warn "~a is not of type ~a" value type))))
```

What it does is ensure the input is cleared (there is no pending/buffered values to be read), it prints a new-line if necessary, a custom message, flush the output stream, then read a value and check if that value matches a given type. If that's not the case the code is executed in a loop.

For example, you can produce a property list as follows:

```
(defun input-bmi-parameters ()
  (list
   :weight (prompt "Weight (kgs): " '(integer 0 1000))
   :height (prompt "Height (meters): " '(real 0 5))))
```

Finally you can piece all the functions together, write a title, write the output, etc:

```
(defun bmi-program ()
  (format *query-io* "~&BMI Calculator. Enter weight and height and be judged.~%")
  (let ((parameters (input-bmi-parameters)))
    ...))
```

Notice how I am using `let` to introduce a local variable `parameters` bound to a list (see also in `prompt` where I use local variable `value`). Apart from interacting with the `*query-io*`, the code does not have side-effects, all the state is contained in the function. That means that you could run more than one `bmi-program` in parallel,  without them messing around with the same set of global variables: you could have a server where each connection executes `bmi-program` in a different thread, in which `*query-io*` is bound to the current TCP stream.

Comment: "a lot of undeclared global variables" I think these variables are introduced by [`prog`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_prog_.htm) and are local. I also thought this is a typical "setf vs let" beginner mistake, but that `prog` part seems correct.

Comment: @MartinPůda oh right, I didn't even see it :)